# When I try to cache with nginx I get 404 on resources

Tags: nginx, cache

I googled around and found some scripts on how to cache static resources on nginx, the problem is that when I apply these scripts I get 404 on my scripts and styles. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm sorry but I don't know how to copy from nano using putty so I made a picture of how my config looks like. Note that I commented caching section. If I uncomment it my static files will be 404.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place a `root` directive in your `server` block to specify where your static files are.

Comment: So if my website is stored in `/var/websites/site/` I should add `root /var/websites/site/;` because that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your URL `http://site/main.css` is stored at `/var/websites/site/main.css`, then `root /var/websites/site/;` after `server_name` line should work.

Comment: But what if I have styles.css in `/var/websites/site/content/css/` and `scripts.js` in `/var/websites/site/content/js/`?

Comment: The `root` directive has to point to the public HTML root of your site. So, if your css is accessible via URL `http://site/content/css/main.css`, you use `root /var/websites/site/;` as the root statement.